# How to code for Wp all import to update ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wpallimport

I am following  this 
http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/addon-dev/overview/

This is the function for basic import

```
function my_addon_import_function( $post_id, $data, $import_options, $article ) {
  global $my_addon;

  $fields = array(
    'property_location',
    'property_address'
  );

  foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
    if ( empty( $article['ID'] ) or $my_addon->can_update_meta( $field, $import_options ) ) {
      update_post_meta( $post_id, $field, $data[ $field ] );      
    }    
  }  
}
```

how can i use to update the acf field? Pls help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to update ACF fields in the foreach instead of the post meta. You can do that with the [update_field()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) function like this:

```
function my_addon_import_function( $post_id, $data, $import_options, $article ) {
    global $my_addon;

    $fields = array(
        'property_location',
        'property_address'
    );

    foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
        if ( empty( $article['ID'] ) or $my_addon->can_update_meta( $field, $import_options ) ) {

            update_field( $field, $data[$field], $post_id );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer i have tried it but it does not seems to work..even though the $data is having the content in it.

Comment: update_post_meta($post_id, $field ,  $data[$field]); i used this ..it works but out put is like {"wppl_greeting":"awsome!!"}

Comment: it returns a json

Comment: If it returns json you can do [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) first. Then it will be stored in an object. If you want it in an array instead you can do `json_decode( $data['field'], true );` then you can use update_field( which should work with ACF fields. otherwise update_post_meta() ) with the value that you get back from json_decode.

Comment: hey, your answer works but you have to change $data[$field] other wise it returns json. thanks ..any idea on updating the image field?

Comment: Yes, you should take a look at the first user contributed notes of [media_handle_sideload](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_sideload/#user-contributed-notes) . That will upload and create an attachment which you need to update an ACF Field with. ACF image fields need an attachment id as the value. so after you got the uploading of the image working you can use update_field() again with the id of the attachment.